# Select permission denied

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I am hoping this will be a simple question. I am using IIS 7.5 / Visual Web Dev 2010 Express.

I know why this error appears :) it's a security/user issue. The problem is, I don't know what account/permissions this intranet is using that's causing the issue.

I use a simple authentication method that detects the user ID. If they're on that list, they are allowed to look at the page. This is done through:

> [allow users] and [deny users]

(Brackets substituted for arrows.)

Authentication mode is set to Windows.

There is another intranet site that users can access- I have read and write permissions on that database that this web site uses. That intranet site works for me, but this gives me a security error.

I'm thinking that by using this authentication method, that it switches to a system profile which tries to access it and gets denied. Is there a generic system profile you guys know of that would cause such an error? Is that even a right assumption or is it a security setting that's related to my username?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe this could be helpful for someone in the future who is also facing the same problem. I am not sure where to find this, but apparently I had left out or there was not a tag called identity impersonate. By just having the authentication mode set to Windows, I thought it would take care of everything.

I am assuming that if you use Windows authentication, a system account will try and access the SQL database. Because that system account (whatever it may be, there is one defined somewhere but I forgot the name of it) does not have access, that permission error gets thrown.

What will make the web page use the user permission is with this tag:

> [identity impersonate="true"/]

Substitute brackets with arrows.